# Neural network's Validation accuracy is improving but accuracy, loss and val_loss are mostly *nan* during learning

Tags: keras, neural-network, model, loss-function

When I ran a basic Neural Network using Keras API,the validation accuracy is improving but **accuracy**, **loss** and **val_loss** are mostly *nan*

Running environment and other info

- Keras version: '2.4.0'
- TensorFlow version: '2.3.0'
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- GPU: Radeon RX 580 Series
- Python running in Jupyter Notebook (there is no library version issue that I am aware about)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping 
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

### data
tnc_data = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/3mqdgfkz7fjtlf8/titanic_all_numeric.csv?dl=1')
### data prep
X = tnc_data.drop( 'survived', axis= 1 ).to_numpy()
X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)
Y = to_categorical( tnc_data['survived'] )

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
e_stop_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience= 10)

### model 
model1 = keras.Sequential()
model1.add( keras.layers.Dense( units= 10, activation= 'relu', input_shape= (X.shape[1],)  ) )
model1.add( keras.layers.Dense( units= 10, activation= 'relu' ) )
model1.add( keras.layers.Dense( units= 2, activation= 'softmax' ) )
model1.compile( optimizer= 'adam', loss= 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'] ) 
model1_training = model1.fit( x= X, y= Y, epochs= 15,
                              validation_split = 20./100,
                              callbacks= [e_stop_monitor],
                              verbose= 2 )
```

The result that I observed is:

```
Epoch 1/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: 0.4823 - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4637 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: nan - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.6425 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: nan - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6425 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 4/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: nan - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.6425 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 5/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: 0.5471 - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.6425 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 6/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: nan - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.6425 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 7/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: nan - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.6425 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 8/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: 0.5941 - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5307 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 9/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: nan - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5196 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 10/15
23/23 - 0s - accuracy: 0.6296 - loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5978 - val_loss: nan
```

Thank you all for your kind help...

Answer (score 0):

First, you should compare the accuracy of training, validation and test data.
If the training accuracy is low, the model doesn't deal with the complexity of data, then you should adjust the parameters.
if the validation accuracy is low, it means that your model is overfitting
if the test accuracy is low, it means you need more diverse training data

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your network is you have 2 classes(0 & 1) but you are using categorical crossentropy loss which works for more than two classes. You should probably be using binary crossentropy loss. And also I'm not sure how well softmax will work in this condition try adding sigmoid function instead of softmax. Ideally both should give the same result.

Comment: This answer is not accurate. Multi-class cross-entropy loss should work in the same way for only two classes, and softmax is fine as long as the final outputs before softmax are 2-dimensional (they are in this case).

Comment: Thanks Niranjan and Mathais for your input. I think Mathais is correct. The fault is intrinsically not with the loss or activation function. 
I tried changing the loss and activation function (to binary_crossentropy and sigmoid) but got different kind of error as shown:


InvalidArgumentError:  Size 1 must be non-negative, not -4194304
  [[node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-124-868bffdec3d5>:21) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_42188]

Function call stack:
train_function